# Scraping data from HTML table usin xpath and LXML or selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I need to extract data from HTML table from this website:
https://1x2.lucksport.com/result_en.shtml?dt=2019-04-12&cid=156

I use Python, selenium and lxml with xpath

I want to extract each match odds 
The problem is that each match is in 2 row 
two : tr class="dtd2", then come two: tr class="dtd1"

I need the xpath that allow to extract the first row and his following row

```
driver.get(u)
t = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
for i in t.xpath('//*[@id="odds_tb"]/table/tbody/tr[@class="dtd2"]/td[1]/text()'):
```

Comment: Can you update the question exactly which values are you trying to extract from the table? Your current xpath points to two different cells within the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more verbose method

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import copy

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://1x2.lucksport.com/result_en.shtml?dt=2019-04-12&cid=156')
WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#odds_tb tr[class]")))
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
rows = soup.select('#odds_tb tr[class]')
results = []
i = 1 
headers = ['Competition', 'Date', 'Match' ,'OddsType', 'Home Win', 'Draw', 'Away Win', 'Result']

for row in rows[1:]:    
    cols = [td.text for td in row.select('td')]

    if (i % 2 == 1):
        record = {'Competition' : cols[0],
                  'Date' : cols[1],
                  'Match' : ' v '.join([cols[2], cols[6]]),
                  'OddsType' : 'average early odds',
                  'Home Win' : cols[3], 
                  'Draw' : cols[4], 
                  'Away Win' : cols[5],
                  'Result' : cols[7]}
    else:
        record['OddsType'] = 'average live odds'
        record['Home Win'] = cols[0] 
        record['Draw'] = cols[1] 
        record['Away Win'] = cols[2]
    results.append(copy.deepcopy(record))
    i+=1

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = headers)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
d.quit()
```

Comment: great, it works, we can add the competition and the date and the result for each match ?

Comment: I can be found here [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus)

Comment: if I would like to scrape scores from each date, you think we can automate  it ? on the url, date can be changed, https://1x2.lucksport.com/result_en.shtml?dt=2019-04-12&cid=156 but I don't know how to automate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `selenium` and `pandas` to get the table info.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://1x2.lucksport.com/result_en.shtml?dt=2019-04-12&cid=156")
time.sleep(3)
htmlcontent=driver.page_source
tables=pd.read_html(htmlcontent)
print(tables[14])
```

Comment: it worked but the second row of each game is not synchronized with the upper row

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to iterate the odd trs and then include the "next" tr.
In css that looks like:

```
.dtd1:nth-child(odd),.dtd2:nth-child(odd)
```

You can get odds with xpath too, just add:

```
[position() mod 2 = 1]
```